# C4013: undefined; assuming extern returning int

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

I am trying to create malloc function and in this code:

```
typedef struct hlavicka
{
  unsigned int velkost;
  struct hlavicka *dalsi;
  struct hlavicka *pred;
} HLAVICKA;

struct hlavicka *blok;

void init(void *ptr, unsigned size)
{
  blok = ptr;
  blok->velkost = 1;
  blok->dalsi = blok;
  blok->pred = blok;
}

void *memory_alloc(unsigned int size)
{
  HLAVICKA *ptr = NULL;
  int nova_velkost = size + sizeof(HLAVICKA);
  ptr = find_fit(nova_velkost);
  if ((long)ptr == -1)
      return NULL;
  else
  {
      *(unsigned int *)ptr = size;
      return (void *)((char*)ptr + sizeof(HLAVICKA));
  }
}

void *find_fit(unsigned int size)
{
  HLAVICKA *pom_ptr;
  for (pom_ptr = blok->dalsi; (pom_ptr != blok) && (pom_ptr->velkost < size); pom_ptr = pom_ptr->dalsi)
      if (pom_ptr != blok)
        return pom_ptr;
}

int main()
{
  char region[50], *pointer;
  init(region, 50);

  pointer = (char*)memory_alloc(10);

  return 0;
}
```

I have a three errors:

```
warning C4013: 'find_fit' undefined; assuming extern returning int
warning C4047: '=' : 'HLAVICKA *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
error C2040: 'find_fit' : 'HLAVICKA *(unsigned int)' differs in levels of indirection from 'int ()'
```

Where is the problem? In struct or function type?

Comment: You need a function prototype for `find_fit` - an advance declaration.

Comment: Why do I need it?

Comment: The compiler has told you. It made assumptions about the unknown function, which proved to be wrong.

Comment: @JakubRosina, you need it because the function `find_fit()` was used in `memory_alloc()` before it was defined. If you move it above `memory_alloc()`, you won't need the forward declaration.

Answer (score 2):

In `memory_alloc()`, when your compiler meets the function `find_fit()`, it doesn't known anything about it since it is defined later. Therefore, the compiler is forced to make assumptions about `find_fit()` and those assumptions don't match your code at all. That's why the compiler yells at you.

The solution: the compiler must know about `find_fit()` before entering `memory_alloc()`

- either declare it above `memory_alloc()` (or in a separate `.h` file you include at the top of your `.c` file) with the line

  ```
  void *find_fit(unsigned int size);
  ```
- or define it before `memory_alloc()`, i.e. just move `find_fit()` above it